# Emphasize background conversation to understand what someone in the background is saying?

Tags: audacity, background, izotope

How to get background conversation in a sound record? To understand what someone in the background is saying during :

1) a recorded phone call.
2) In a noisy cafe.

How would one go about it using either audacity or izotope RX 7?
Have these 2 so if these can do the job , would appreciate detailed instructions.
If not suggestions for better software are welcome too.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is only to be found in CSI [*city of your choice*] not in real life.
Izotope is about as good as it gets, but it needs a reasonably constant noise-floor to suppress.

You could try a multi-band compressor to lift everything to the same level, but you'd be unlikely to be able to push the foreground conversation back far enough for the background to appear above it.

You might try one copy flatline compressed & another copy background suppressed using Izotope or similar & try phase-inverting one against the other.

Most phones these days try to eliminate background interference before transmission, so your efforts would be less likely to succeed on a modern mobile phone.

Comment: "Most phones these days try to eliminate background interference before transmission, so your efforts would be less likely to succeed on a modern mobile phone."

I am trying to enhance voices in the background I could hear clearly while on call but not that clear in the recording.  Tried multiple apps but same issue.

Comment: Apps won't help you @Hrishikesh - this is just basic physics. If you want a good recording you need to record well - you can't expect to fix afterwards.